# prestashop: obtener valores de la ulr desde un modulo

Tags: prestashop

Buen día comunidad, soy nuevo en prestashop por lo que tengo un problema, esstoy usando prestahop 1.6.

Necesito obtener el valor de la url desde un modulo.

La el valor que quiero tomar es "category_rewrite" de la siguente ulr:

```
dominio.com/index.php?category_rewrite=ropa-dama&controller=category
```

el porque de tomar este valor, bueno es que estoy usando el modulo para eliminar los IDs de las url, entonces la clase css "active" del menu deja de funcionar.

En el modulo de menu tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
public function getCurrentCategoriesId($lang_id = NULL) {
        if (isset($_GET['category_rewrite'])) {
            $link_rewrite = $_GET['category_rewrite'];
            $id_lang = $this->context->language->id;
        $id_shop = $this->context->shop->id;
        $sql = 'SELECT `id_category`
                FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang
                WHERE `link_rewrite` = \''.pSQL($link_rewrite).'\'
                AND `id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.'
                AND `id_shop` = '.(int)$id_shop;
        $id_category = (int)Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue($sql);
        } else {
            $link_rewrite = false;
        }

        $lastCate = new Category((int) $id_category);
        $parentCate = $lastCate->getParentsCategories($lang_id);
        $arrayCateCurrent = array();
        foreach ($parentCate as $pcate) {
            $arrayCateCurrent[] = $pcate['id_category'];
        }
        return $arrayCateCurrent;
    }
```

pero sigo sin obtener el valor de la url, el codigo original es el siguientey funciona correctamente cuando desactivo el modulo de urls y se muestra el id:

```
public function getCurrentCategoriesId($lang_id = NULL) {
        if (isset($_GET['id_category'])) {
            $lastCateId = $_GET['id_category'];
        } else {
            $lastCateId = 0;
        }

        $lastCate = new Category((int) $lastCateId);
        //echo $lastCate->name[1]; echo '--------';
        $parentCate = $lastCate->getParentsCategories($lang_id);
        $arrayCateCurrent = array();
        foreach ($parentCate as $pcate) {
            $arrayCateCurrent[] = $pcate['id_category'];
        }
        return $arrayCateCurrent;
    }
```

espero puedan ayudarme, saludos

Comment: No es necesario añadir solucionado al título de la pregunta, solo es necesario marcar una respuesta como correcta como lo has hecho :)

Comment: ok muchas gracias por la aclaratoria, soy nuevo aca.

Comment: Si eres nuevo seria bueno que pases el [tour] para que entiendas la dinámica de SO.

Comment: listo, gracias, lo hare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás sea difícil para alguien el poder ayudarte ya que como mencionas hay un modulo de por medio que altera las variables, lo que yo te recomendaría es que que en ese método hagas un die del `$_GET` para que antes puedas revisar de cuales son las variables que dispones ya que es probable que no exista `category_rewrite`, puedes hacerlo con `d($_GET)`.

Si encuentras una variable que te sirva para obtener el `id_category`, no utilices `$_GET['la_varible']`, por motivos de seguridad y prácticas mandatorias de PrestaShop obtenla de la siguiente manera `Tools::getValue('la_variable')`.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta amigo, y si efectivamente, ya eh probado con esa funcion y sigo sin obtener el valor de la url. Lo que me parece raro es que con el codigo original funciona correctamente.

Comment: En el código original que muestras se obtiene el id de categoría directamente, y tu estas intentando obtenerlo partiendo de la url reescrita, ¿en tu código modificado no te permite obtenerla con `(int)Tools::getValue('id_category')`?

Comment: no, ya que en la url no hace ningun llamado al id de la categoria, por eso fue que realize una consulta a la BD para buscar el valor obtenido, pero el problema esta en que no obtengo ningun valor desde la url, si hago un isset($_GET['category_rewrite']) este me dice q esta activo pero no obtine el valor

Comment: Podrias decirme puntualmente que te regresa esto: `d(Tools::getValue('category_rewrite'));`

Comment: amigo muchas gracias por responder, no me muestra nada, pero si hago la misma funcion con "controller" si me muestra un valor que es "category".

Comment: amigo @Rolige ya encontre la solucion a mi problema, use la funcion Tools::getAllValues y esta me mostro que se esta imprimiendo de alguna forma el id de la categoria por lo que reescribi el codigo original, el $_GET por Tools::getValue('id_category') y funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias por las tus respuestas. Saludos

Comment: Excelente, si pudieras cerrar la pregunta seria perfecto.